# How to use multiple Ajax calls to generate serverside response data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have two distinct Ajax queries (shown below) which give different parts of the server side data required by DataTables.

```
// for each page, returns 40 rows of records as json string from table
ajax.aspx?get=list&page=1

// returns total count for the table
ajax.aspx?get=count
```

How can I combine the data returned by these two ajax calls into the one JSON data set required by the DataTables jQuery plugin?

From DataTables documentation, the serverside page is supposed to return `totalRecords` & `data` in single query for processing, which doesn't work for my case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );

// ajax result for server_processing.php:
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [...]
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a 3rd api call that combines the results of the first two if you cant modify the first to return the data from the second too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to combine those two server-side responses to the Ajax call into a single one that returns all necessary data, as recommended in the DataTables [server-side documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). If that really isn't an option, a workaround I can think of is to have a second Ajax call inside the first one's success callback function, and then to stitch together the two JSON files.

This may sound ugly (and it is), which is why if at all possible it would be advantageous to combine the two Ajax calls.

A quick mock-up of what that could look like would be something like:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.recordsTotal = $.ajax({
            "url": "ExampleURL.php",
            "dataType": "json",
            "async": false //Necessary, see @KevinB's comment
            //Other configuration options (link below)
        }).count; //or whatever object you need from this call
    }
  }
} );
```

The other configuration options for the jQuery Ajax call can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Again, I'd like to stress that using the two Ajax calls is unfortunate, and ideally you could handle all data in a single Ajax call.

**Edit:**
Another suggestion which @Kevin B's comment made me think of is: could you not modify one of the serverside responses to call the other and return all the data at once? That would probably be a more optimal solution than this (although still sub-par to having one all-encompassing call).

Comment: would that even work? `d.recordsTotal = $.ajax` that would require the ajax to be synchronous (and coded slightly differently), or the datatable plugin would need to know that `recordsTotal` is a promise it should wait for..

Comment: @KevinB I didn't think about that, this is all pretty non-standard (really it should be one ajax call). You can specify that the ajax request be made synchronously (which I'll add to the example).